# Alternate tempo indications in Janáček's Mládí

Tags: tempo, woodwinds

What is the reason for the alternate tempo markings in Janáček's Mládí here and elsewhere? Is one of them aimed at players who are no longer in the first flush of 'Youth' maybe?

[image]

Comment: It looks as if it's reflecting two sources. I would think there would be an explanatory note somewhere. What edition is this and where did you find it?

Comment: It's the one on IMSLP as mentioned in @Aaron's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [edition on IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/Ml%C3%A1d%C3%AD_(Jan%C3%A1%C4%8Dek%2C_Leo%C5%A1)) (which appears to be the one in the original question) is the second edition. And the introductory notes explain that the tempi in the second edition are different from those in the first.

> The first performance of the suite took place at Brno, on 21st October 1924, to celebrate Janáček's seventieth birthday; the concert was arranged by the State Conservatoire of Music. The Hudební Matice Umělecké Besedy published the score, parts and a piano reduction of the suite for the first time in 1925. This new, second edition of the score has been revised to match the copy rewritten under the guidance of the composer after the first performance of the work at Brno, but not in accordance with the original manuscript.

From the Czech portion of the introduction:

> Th[is] new edition in the Collection of pocket scores is based on the same principle as was applied in the printing of the score when it was first published, with the difference that, in the movement rules, it first respects Janáček's original data from Sedláček's copy[,] and everything that was ... in the first [edition] changed or added to are marked with brackets. The first of these data preserves as an image the composer's own ideas, interesting even if perhaps not always accurately expressed (although, for example, the Moderato designation at the beginning of the second movement seems to describe that idea better than the confused Andante sostenuto), the second group of data is maintained because it was printed during the composer's lifetime, and therefore probably with his consent.•) Otherwise, in places where it was desirable, the new edition according to the printed voices is supplemented with a few force marks, which are also indicated by brackets for differentiation, and further the printed ones are corrected [for] errors and [deletion of] superfluous shift signs, as always with Janáček and here in the original wording very common.<sup>1</sup>

The footnote also gives an example of Janáček's changes in tempo. It translates:

> For comparison, I also list here the metronomic numbers in which he performed them with the Pralsky Wind Quintet, different from those in the first edition of the score....

---

<sup>1</sup> Original text

> Nové vydání ve Sbírce kapesních partitur vychází ze stejné zásady, jaká byla v tisku partitury uplatněna při prvním jejím vydání, s tím však rozdílem, že v pohy­bových předpisech respektuje na prvém místě původní Janáčkovy údaje ze Sedláč­kova opisu a všechno, co v nich bylo v prvém vydání změněno nebo k nim přidáno, má označeno uzávorkoviním. První z těchto údajů zachovává jako obraz vlastní představy skladatelovy, zajímavé i když snad ne všady přesně vyjádřené (ačkoliv na př. označení Moderato na začátku druhé věty zdá se onu představu lépe vystiho­vati, než zaměněné Andante sostenuto), druhou skupinu údajů podržuje proto, že byla otištěná za skladatelova života a tedy patrně s jeho souhlasem.•) Jinak v mís­tech, v nichž to bylo žádoucí, je nové vydání podle tistěných hlasů doplněno několika znaménky silovými, která pro odlišení jsou rovněž označena uzávorkováním, a dále jsou v něm opraveny tiskové chyby a vypuštěna přebytečná znaménka posuvná, jako vždy u Janáčka i zde v původním znění velmi častá.